# Adding custom theme template to custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template, theme-options

I've created a new custom post type called MemberPost and want it to follow a slightly different template to my main index (which is where main news is kept). I've created a custom post type and inserted this into my `functions.php`.

```
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');

add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_member_post' );

function register_cpt_member_post() {

$labels = array(
    'name' => __( 'MemberPost', 'member-post' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'MemberPost', 'member-post' ),
    'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'member-post' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New MemberPost', 'member-post' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit MemberPost', 'member-post' ),
    'new_item' => __( 'New MemberPost', 'member-post' ),
    'view_item' => __( 'View MemberPost', 'member-post' ),
    'search_items' => __( 'Search MemberPost', 'member-post' ),
    'not_found' => __( 'No memberpost found', 'member-post' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No memberpost found in Trash', 'member-post' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent MemberPost:', 'member-post' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'MemberPost', 'member-post' ),
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'description' => 'Post containing the months member content',
    'supports' => array( 'editor', 'title', 'thumbnail'),
    'public' => false,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'member-post'),
    'capability_type' => 'post'
);

register_post_type( 'member_post', $args );
flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

I then created the single-memberPost.php but I can't get the theme to use this custom post template.

Comment: Please make use of our site search before asking duplicate questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File should be `single-member_post.php` instead of `single-memberPost.php`.

In `single-{posttype}` , `{post_type}` is the `$post_type` argument of the `register_post_type()` function.

Never use `flush_rewrite_rules();` in `init` use it only on theme/plugin deactivate or activate.

Since this is a theme you can use it on `after_switch_theme` hook.

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_cpt_init' );
function register_cpt_member_post() {
    register_post_type( ... );
}

function my_rewrite_flush() {
    register_cpt_member_post();
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'my_rewrite_flush' );
```

Comment: Custom post types should not be registered in themes, it should be done in a plugin

Comment: @PieterGoosen , yes.

Answer (score 0):

Your post type (`member_post`) doesn't match your template slug (`memberPost`). Whichever you choose, it must be all lower case.